# Having trouble building this small comparison in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, int

I'm using Entity Framework as my ORM. I'm trying to get all grade instances where the GradeInstanceId is equal to X, and the Year is equal to this year.

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
private void LoadGradeInstances()
{
    GradeInstanceRepository repo = new GradeInstanceRepository();
    int gradeId = 5; //For example.
    cmbGradeInstance.DataSource = repo.FindAll().Where(g => g.GradeId == gradeID && g.Year == currentYear);
}
```

I'm receiving the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type 'System.DateTime?'
>   and 'int'

How can I solve this comparison?

Thank you.

Comment: is there a chance that g.Year is a DateTime, and thus you'd need g.Year.Year?

Comment: @Yuriy: Exactly correct. :) Hm...with that in mind how would I create this lambda expression?

Comment: Change g.Year to g.Year.Year, and tell whoever stored it that way you'll make them rewrite everything in binary.

Comment: @Yuriy: How would you suggest we save the year value in our database? A plain number would suffice?

Comment: Yes. Mostly to match the `DateTime.Year` property. In general that's how I've seen it stored. Don't know the details behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to compare an Object to a primitive. Try comparing the DateTime's year component to your `int` year variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Not for sure what type 'Year' so I can't say for sure it will work.

```
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
private void LoadGradeInstances()
{
    GradeInstanceRepository repo = new GradeInstanceRepository();
    int gradeId = 5; //For example.
    cmbGradeInstance.DataSource = repo.FindAll().Where(g => g.GradeId == gradeID && g.Year.Year == currentYear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that currentYear is of DateTime. In that case you may need to do

`currentYear.Year`

Or g.Year is of DateTime in that case you need to do

`g.Year >= datetimeStartOfYear && g.Year <= datetimeEndOfYear`

Comment: Compiler error: "'int' does not contain a definition for 'Year'"

Answer (score 0):

Try `g.Year.Year`:

```
(g => g.GradeId == gradeID && g.Year.Year == currentYear)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
private void LoadGradeInstances()
{
    GradeInstanceRepository repo = new GradeInstanceRepository();
    int gradeId = 5; //For example.
    cmbGradeInstance.DataSource = repo.FindAll().Where(g => g.GradeId == gradeID && g.Year.Value.Year == currentYear);
}
```